# expand colnames to match the last known one

Tags: r, dataframe

Assume a data.frame:

```
df <- structure(list(Dates = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2017-05-02", 
      "2017-07-30"), class = "factor"), Var1 = c(1, 2), X1 = c(3, 4
       ), X2 = c(5, 6), Var2 = c(7, 8), X3 = c(9, 10), X4 = c(11, 12
       )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Which looks like this:

```
      Dates Var1 X1 X2 Var2 X3 X4
1 2017-05-02    1  3  5    7  9 11
2 2017-07-30    2  4  6    8 10 12
```

Is there a way to expand the known colnames to the consecutive ones? So it will look like:

```
       Dates Var1 Var1 Var1 Var2 Var2 Var2
1 2017-05-02    1    3    5    7    9   11
2 2017-07-30    2    4    6    8   10   12
```

The actual data frame is much much larger with much more known and unknown variables so an automated approach is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to rename columns that start with "X", we could `replace` them with `NA` and then use `na.locf` to get previous names of the column.

```
library(zoo)

names(df) <- na.locf(replace(names(df), grepl("^X", names(df)), NA))
df
#       Dates Var1 Var1 Var1 Var2 Var2 Var2
#1 2017-05-02    1    3    5    7    9   11
#2 2017-07-30    2    4    6    8   10   12
```